# Building OpenCV with Clang 5 in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, build, clang

I'm trying to build OpenCV in Windows 7 with Clang 5.0.0 but Cmake does not recognize the option and, therefore, there is no compilation available.

The system contains Clang 5.0.0, MSVC 2013 Express and Cmake 3.10.0.

Googling the solution does not show any valid results.

There is any way to generate the OpenCV dll/lib with Clang (and LLVM) capabilites/dependencies?

If there is a workaround evading MSVC, I accept it, too.

Thanks in advance.